# Oauth2 in Symfony2

Tags: php, oauth, symfony, oauth-2.0

I'd like to use some APIs, foursquare for example, in my Symfony2 project. The problem is that instead of the 2 great FOS bundles concerning Twitter/Facebook, I'm not finding anything on OAuth (I tried the EtcPasswdOAuthBundle but did not manage to make it work because of a missing file I guess).

Moreover, I'd like to make it work with FOSUserBundle.

So, if you could give me some help, I do not understand how to manage OAuth with Symfony ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 20):

Two years later, but for all who might step over this link while searching for a solution:

The new OAuth2 package for client integration in Symfony2 is the [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle), the KNPLabs is no longer maintained. - the server pendant is the [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is using OAuth2, I guess you can easily make a Foursquare bundle based on the FacebookBundle.

Comment: Yeah I know and I tried to, but I'm a little bit confused with all of the process and how Symfony's authentification core is working ...

Answer (score 1):

[Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) is a really good client to do http request with objects.

You can add [guzzle-oauth2-plugin](https://github.com/commerceguys/guzzle-oauth2-plugin) to handle OAuth easily. There is a [tutorial](http://blog.ajouve.com/symfony2/oauth2/microservice/2015/12/19/oauth-microservice-symfony.html#display-the-date) if you need help.